# How to prevent duplicate booking and set time slots using nextjs and prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, next.js

Bellow I have my nextjs app booking system. I am new to this and trying to make my own website for simple booking. I have it all connected to netlify. I am able to collect booking time and name etc.

I am using netlify forms for that however I am trying to stop duplicated bookings and some last two hours were some last three hours so I need to be able to set a different block time in order to do this. I have no idea...

I connected my nextjs app to prisma and created a CRUD based of tutorials. However I do not know where to start or how the logic would even look to do that?

Below is what I have.

`testme.jsx`

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { prisma } from '../lib/prisma'


interface Notes{
  notes: {
    id: string
    title: string
    time: string
    email: string
    date: string
    content: string
  }[]
}

interface FormData {
  title: string
  time: string
  email: string
  date: string
  content: string
  id: string
}

const Home = ({notes}: Notes) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState<FormData>({title: '', email: '', date: '', time: '', content: '', id: ''})

  const router = useRouter()

  const refreshData = () => {
    router.replace(router.asPath)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchForm = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/create')
      const data = await res.json();
      setForm(data)
    }
    fetchForm();
  }, []);


    async function create(data: FormData) {
    try {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/create', {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST'
      }).then(() => {
        if(data.id) {
          deleteNote(data.id)
          setForm({title: '', time: '', email: '', date: '', content: '', id: ''})
          refreshData()
        } else {
          setForm({title: '', time: '', email: '', date: '', content: '', id: ''})
          refreshData()

        }
      }
        )
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


  async function deleteNote(id: string) {
    try {
     fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/note/${id}`, {
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
       method: 'DELETE'
     }).then(() => {
       refreshData()
     })
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error); 
    }
  }

  async function pauseNote(time: string) {
    try {
     fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/note/${time}`, {
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
       method: 'DELETE'
     }).then(() => {
       refreshData()
     })
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error); 
    }
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (data: FormData) => {
    try {
     create(data) 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-2xl mt-4">Notes</h1>

      
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        handleSubmit(form)
      }} className='w-auto min-w-[25%] max-w-min mx-auto space-y-6 flex flex-col items-stretch'>
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={form.title}
          onChange={e => setForm({...form, title: e.target.value})}
          className="border-2 rounded border-gray-600 p-1"
        />
         <input type="time"
          placeholder="time"
          value={form.time}
          onChange={e => setForm({...form, time: e.target.value})}
          className="border-2 rounded border-gray-600 p-1"
        />
          <input type="date"
          placeholder="date"
          value={form.date}
          onChange={e => setForm({...form, date: e.target.value})}
          className="border-2 rounded border-gray-600 p-1"
        />

<input type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={form.email}
          onChange={e => setForm({...form, email: e.target.value})}
          className="border-2 rounded border-gray-600 p-1"
        />
        <textarea 
          placeholder="Content"
          value={form.content}
          onChange={e => setForm({...form, content: e.target.value})}
          className="border-2 rounded border-gray-600 p-1"
        />
        <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded p-1">Add +</button>
      </form>
      <div className="w-auto min-w-[25%] max-w-min mt-20 mx-auto space-y-6 flex flex-col items-stretch">
        <ul>
          {notes.map(note => (
            <li key={note.id} className="border-b border-gray-600 p-2">
              <div className="flex justify-between">
                <div className="flex-1">
                  <h3 className="font-bold">{note.title}</h3>
                  <p className="text-sm">{note.content}</p>
                  <p className="text-sm">{note.time}</p>
                </div>
                <button onClick={() => setForm({title: note.title, date: note.date, email: note.email, time: note.time, content: note.content, id: note.id})} className="bg-blue-500 mr-3 px-3 text-white rounded">Update</button>
                <button onClick={() => deleteNote(note.id)} className="bg-red-500 px-3 text-white rounded">X</button>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const notes = await prisma.note.findMany({
    select: {
      title: true,
      time: true,
      email: true,
      date: true,
      id: true,
      content: true
    }
  })

  return {
    props: {
      notes
    }
  }
}
```

inside my API folder i have

`create.ts`

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { prisma } from "../../lib/prisma";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse){
    const {title, time, content, email, date} = req.body

    try {
        await prisma.note.create({
            data: {
                title,
                time,
                email,
                date,
                content
            }
        })
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Booking made'})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Sorry time has been taken");
    }
}
```

Along side create.ts I have a note folder inside my api with
`[id].tsx`

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { prisma } from "../../../lib/prisma";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse){
    const noteId = req.query.id

    if(req.method === 'DELETE') {
        const note = await prisma.note.delete({
            where: {id: Number(noteId)}
        })
        res.json(note)
    } else {
        console.log("Note could not be created");
    }
}
```

I am sorry if this is a lot If you see my GitHub commits I promise I've been trying just need guidance?

Comment: omorfia.netlify.app if you want to see the website and any tips must be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test your code but you have the next logic.

1. Once your/few visitors land on your page, you need to show available time/booking. (you did it)
2. Once he filled info and clicked submit you need to: *validate info on the page or with typescript*, *then send it to your API*. (you did it)
3. Once data is sent to `create.ts`, you need **firstly check if this appointment wasn't booked and only then create a new appointment**. I am not sure that your try-catch is working, check really these lines of code.
4. You can check [this lib](https://swr.vercel.app/#overview) to keep updating your info from DB in real-time. (to replace the useless router.asPath in your code, you need to re-fetch data, not reload the page)

P.S. doubling can be a problem because of the hidden "double click" of submit button, block your  button (for example with useState)for 3-5 secs after submitting or until you have return function with status from your API.